# Laravel get the latest non incrementing value before save without race condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to increment a non-autoincrementing integer column in my model that is completely independent from the model's auto incrementing ID.

To simplify what I am trying to say Consider a table that holds books. In this table we have four fields:

```
Book_id (auto incrementing ID)
book_title  (a string) 
book_contents (Also a string for the purposes of this example)
book_edition (an integer representing the edition of the book. Think College textbooks)
```

So lets say that we have a book called "harry potter" and another called "mickey mouse". Our database currently looks like this

```
id:            1
book_title:    "Harry Potter" 
book_contents: "Book Contents"
book_edition:  1 
--------------------------
id:            2
book_title:    "Mickey Mouse"
book_contents: "This is a book about Mickey"
book_edition:  1
```

Now lets say that for some reason, the "Harry Potter" book had to be significantly changed, be it for a "directors cut" or whatever the book equivalent of that is, or some other reason. This entry is going to look like the following

```
id:            3
book_title:    "Harry Potter" 
book_contents: "Updated book contents"
book_edition:  2
```

My question is what is the best way to go about grabbing the original book edition in Laravel 5+?

Do I need to actually do a Model::where( {{ query to get latest }} ) or can I handle this another way? I see there is an increment function but it's not documented very well

As a secondary question, if I did do a Model::where like mentioned above, if I wrap it in a Laravel DB::transaction am I protected from the possible race condition where two people update the Harry Potter book at the same time?
Example

```
function saveBook()
{
    DB::transaction(function ($arr) {

          $latest = Book::where('book_title', '=', 'Harry Potter')->orderBy("book_edition", "desc")->first();

          $this->book_edition = $latest->book_edition + 1;
          $this->save();
      });
}
```

Is it possible to encounter a race condition here? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Making a composite unique index from `book_title` and `book_edition` should fix the problem from the start:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `books` ADD UNIQUE `unique_edition`(`book_title`, `book_edition`);
```

Adding a transaction in this case does not offer any benefits as you're only doing one write operation, which while dependent on the result of the read one, would be already protected from any race conditions by the unique index constraint.

To handle unique exceptions you can do this:

```
function saveBook()
{
    ...

    $latestEdition = Book::where('book_title', 'Harry Potter')->max('book_edition');
    $this->book_edition = $latestEdition + 1;

    try {
        $this->save();
    } catch (Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
        // Your checking for 1062 because that's
        // the MySQL error message for duplicate entry
        if ($e->errorInfo[1] == 1062) {
            // set your error message here
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

---

You can also take a look at using [Pessimistic Locking](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#pessimistic-locking), but only as an alternative since locking would just be redundant if you're already using a unique constraint. But in this case a unique constraint makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Wouldn't "Unique" not work in this situation since there can be more than one "edition 2", one for the Harry Potter book and one for Mickey Mouse?

Comment: Ah yes. That sort of makes sense. Just so I am clear, In this case would you not want to have the unique index constraint on the "book_title" and "book_edition" columns instead of ID though?   Also is it possible to make an auto incrementing index in this way?

Comment: Yes, you're right, it seems I'm a little slow today :). I've updated my answer.

Comment: Not a problem at all. Can you also quickly explain how you would increment the edition column in this hypothetical situation?

Comment: Would you just return an error if there was a unique constraint exception thrown (if someone added a new edition before your request was able to update the entry) or retry the operation and try incrementing the edition again. To make this easier to comprehend: if the current edition is 2 and you're trying to update it to 3, but in the mean time someone already updated it to 3, would you like to automatically retry and update it to 4 in the same request or just send a response notifying the user that it could not be updated and he/she should try again?

Comment: Good point. The chances of this happening are very, very slim,so a simple try again message would probably work fine. Thanks again!

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution for handling the rare cases where unique exceptions might happen. With a small improvement to the query fetching the latest edition.